# How to replace " and \ from text files using Java?

Tags: java

I'm using `replace` and `replaceAll` Java functions to replace strings in text files.

I've some issues with some symbols occurring in my text file, such as `"` and `\`

Let's say I have to remove the " from "blablabla", what should i use ? I'm currently using this line but it doesn't work:

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\"blablabla\\"", "");
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `replaceAll` uses regex, and in regex `\` which is written as `\\` in a Java String has a special meaning. Incidentally, that meaning is also to escape characters.

Use `replace` to avoid that, as replace only checks for simple equality. Also, it's probably faster.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me

```
System.out.println("a\\b\"c".replace("\"", "").replace("\\", ""));
```

Generally, documentation for both `replace` and `replaceAll` should provide you enough information. Also, I wouldn't mess with regex (`replaceAll`) if problem can be easily solved with simple string search (`replace`).

Comment: "I wouldn't mess with regex if problem can be easily solved with simple string search" Amen to that.

Comment: Answer by **Goran Jovic** provides some useful info too: you could consider voting for it as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
    String s = "\\tes\\t\"tes\"t";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\|\\\"", ""));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the | in the regular expression?

Comment: @mmccomb: `|` represents "OR"... so, it is either \ or double quote, and of course in Java, you have to escape a special character with another slash, which is why we end up with so many slashes. :)